# Get all nodes on page except for those that have a specific node as an ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using jquery to get all nodes on a page

```
$(*)
```

Then I'd like to filter out any node that is the child of an `svg` node. How can I do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter or http://api.jquery.com/not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the not function:

```
$('*').not($('#ancestorID').find('*'));
```

Note that this is going to be extremely slow.

Comment: @user730569 i think you'd have to rethink your design. No matter what you do, this is going to traverse the entire DOM twice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.filter()`:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('svg').length == 0;
});
```

Also, I think replacing the jQuery `*` selector with `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` might give you a speed boost.

Comment: how would you use it with pure javascript for that speed boost?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$('*').not('svg *');
```

Comment: would `svg *` match all descendents, or only direct children?

Comment: @jbabey all descendants (to match direct children it would be `'svg > *'`)